# C - How to pass an array of strings to another function by reference?

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
void doSomething(){
    char arr[5][10];
    arr[1] = "Bob";
    arr[2] = "Steve";
    arr[3] = "Tim";
    arr[4] = "Ruth";
    arr[5] = "Heather";
    init(arr);

void init(char *array){
    int i;
    newArr[5][10];
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        newArr[i] = *(array + i);
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error saying:

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘init’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>   note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[10]’

Comment: Your compiler is telling you the truth. You have declared `array` to be of type `char *` but you are using it as if it were declared to be of type `char *[]`.

Answer (score 4):

Your data is a 2-dimensional array, so your function needs to take an array of pointers account for this (i.e. `char (*array)[10]` or `char array[][10]`).

Also, in your init function, you can't just copy the strings in to arrays, you either need to copy all the data (as strings with a `strcpy` or character by character with a second loop) or just copy the pointers to the strings (so make your `newArr` variable a `char *newArr[5]`).

If none of this makes any sense, then you should probably brush up on your C Pointer knowledge by reading through the [C FAQ on this topic](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I never said that an array is a pointer. If you want to pass an array to a function, you list the argument as a pointer, and your passed in array decays into a pointer.

Comment: An array decays to a pointer, but only at the first level.  A 2D array does *not* decay into a pointer to a pointer: it decays into a pointer to an array.  So `char [5][10]` decays into `char (*)[10]`, but it does not decay to `char**`.

Comment: @texasbruce Actually after thinking about it, he is right. I agree that he's being dumb for downvoting everything though. Maybe I'll change my answer to be more fitting.

Comment: I downvoted answers *because they are wrong*.  You cannot pass a `char [5][10]` to a function taking `char **`.  Try it.  You get exactly the compiler warning from OP.  And if you try to run it despite the warning, it will crash and not do what you want for the fundamental reason that *arrays are not pointers*.  I cannot stress that enough.  See the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Does this answer look better? It all compiles, uses pointers correctly, etc. While I don't agree with your blind downvoting, I do thank you for helping to fix our knowledge of C pointers.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield http://codepad.org/PkUzCyrj And yes I made a mistake. 2D array is still a pointer to char, not double pointer. But you can see the use of array is the same as pointer in the link I posted.

Comment: Yes, that's much better -- either of the equivalent declarations `char (*array)[10]` or `char array[][10]` are correct, and `char **array` is wrong.  I've removed my downvote.

Comment: @NiklasR You get the same warning as in the original post: `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘test’ from incompatible pointer type` That site might not show warnings.

Answer (score 2):

1) There is no character array assignment in C use `strcpy()` and arrays start at 0 not 1:

```
#include <string.h>
void doSomething(){
    char arr[5][10];
    strcpy(arr[0], "Bob");
    strcpy(arr[1], "Steve");
    strcpy(arr[2], "Tim");
    strcpy(arr[3], "Ruth");
    strcpy(arr[4], "Heather");
    init(arr);
}
```

2) `init()` takes a pointer to char arrays; `newArr[][]` is not declared, add `char`. Add a declaration for `init()` at the beginning of the source. And last but not least: again replace assignment with `strcpy()`.

```
void init(char (*array)[10]);

void doSomething() {...}

void init(char (*array)[10]){
    int i;
    char newArr[5][10];
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        strcpy(newArr[i], array[i]);
    }
}
```

Finally, it might be boring, but take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info and the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) and pick up a book. This will serve you far better and longer than I can.

Comment: thanks for the help, I am just learning C and struggling a bit. As far as arrays starting at 0 I was aware of this and not sure why I started at 1 could have been that I was in a rush. Thanks for the help again.

Answer (score -1):

That's not an error. Its a a warning. As you can see your `arr` in doSomething is a double array (which can be represented using a double pointer) but in init you only take a single pointer. Change that to either a double pointer `**array` or `array[][]*`